# Will the ResizeableWidget package help me with dynamic Table in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, row, move

I have to make a dynamic table in which I can move row-borders and column-borders with gestures. I found a package in Flutter([here](https://pub.dev/packages/resizable_widget/example)). Is it right for a table? Can someone help me?

Comment: I found this one, this may help https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables

Comment: I thought of it too, but I need for the rows and columns not to move over each other in the resizeable widget they stop when they touch each other like I need so I am confused now if it's the right package

Comment: The best way to find out is just to try it out  :D

Comment: Yes I think I will, because I don't have that much of a choice lol, thank you anyways